# Why the view isn`t updating?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app which has 2 fragment containers and takes screenshot feature.
the problem is whenever one of the 2 fragment containers update with another fragment(replaced) and I'm taking a screenshot it shows the previous fragments and not the updated ones.

I'm using `getView().getRootView()` within another fragment in the activity to take the screenshot.
any advice on why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Please be more elaborate about the problem or try to add the code.

If you are not using the FrameLayout, please use this.

Code for Adding FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To add or replace new Fragments use the FragmentTransaction.

```
// Code inside the onCreate method
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.your_placeholder, new TheOtherFragment())
               .commit();
```

To take screen Shot :

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.your_placeholder);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Code for this App: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bK-P9goLz-RTxkIDiQBj9tSXedEBb_-r/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Happy coding and Keep Learning :)

Comment: your take a screenshot code will capture only the fragment and not the whole screen

Comment: You're question wasn't clear enough. But as far as I can guess, the problem might be caused because of the container. When you capture the screen it captures the container.

Comment: No, it does capture the screen but with the wrong fragments(activity starts with certain fragments and changed based on user input)

Comment: So if you want to capture the screenshot of the whole activity then just change the ID of the view from the FrameLayout to the ConstraintLayout or any container that is hosting all your views.

Answer (score 0):

To take screen Shot :

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.id_of_constraintLayout); 
// Here you assign the view Variable to the id of the View hosting all your Views. 

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```